# Setting purchase order number or customer reference number with PayPal Payflow

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

Using PayPal Payflow with hosted pages (and submitting using NV pairs), when reviewing  transactions using the "Search Transactions" functionality in PayPal Manager, there is an ability to search by Purchase Order Number. Additionally, when viewing details for a transaction, there is a Cust Ref #.

I have not been able to figure out how to set either of these values - the customer reference # is always blank, and the search by purchase order never returns results.

Is there any way to set these fields during the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUSTREF for customer reference
PONUM for purchase order

paypal developer reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#processors-requiring-additional-transaction-parameters

Note: These fields might not be supported by every Processing Platform

Comment: Thanks. I can't verify as this works for our scenario since the project is complete now (PayPal seems to have a lot of similar but slightly-different solutions). However, I will mark as accepted as you have provided a link to that documentation that should be useful for other visitors at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution for this, but I did find that `COMMENT1` and `COMMENT2` can be added as names in name-value pairs - this will cause the corresponding fields in the PayPal Manager transaction search to be populated.